# How do i get HTML form value to use in a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html

So im trying to build a temperature converter that uses a single number input form that when submitted, converts to farenheit/celsius but since im a beginner in javascript, i dont know much and i've tried searching but the questions didnt relate to me.

heres my code:

```js
function toCelsius(f) {
  return (f - 32) * (5 / 9);
};

function toFarenheit(c) {
  return (c * 9 / 5) + 32;
};

var numInput = document.getElementById("temp-num").value;
var type = "celsius"; //test
var result = toFarenheit(2);

document.getElementById("resultz").innerHTML = numInput + " in" + type + " is " + result;
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <input type="number" name="temperature" placeholder="50" id="temp-num" />

  <input type="reset" class="bn3637 bn36" />
  <div class="buttons">
    <label for="test">
          <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit();">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <p style="font-size: 15px">TO FAHRENHEIT</p>
          </a>
        </label>
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit();">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span> TO CELSIUS
    </a>
  </div>
</form>
<div class="results">
  <div id="result-title">
    <h2>Result:</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="final-result">
    <p id="resultz"></p>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Put the code into an event listener that runs when the user clicks on one of the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need pass the number in the function, you can consult inside the function with `document.getElementById("temp-num").value` and you can parse value to change string into number

try this:

```
function toCelsius() {
  let numInput = parseFloat(document.getElementById("temp-num").value);
  return (numInput - 32) * (5 / 9);
};
```